# jsp can't redirect page using response

Tags: java, jsp, redirect

I can't redirect to the page with the response.sendRedirect(url);

I can redirect to a link in a common jsp page, but I failed to send it in a function I defined in a jsp page. So in my case, which redirecting within a function, how to solve that?

FYI, the error is "response cannot be resolved".

Below is part of my source code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" 
                         pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.activation.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.io.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>   


<%!
public void sendSMS(String nickName, String setAname, String currAname, 
                                                      String toPhone){
String acctInfo="xxx";
String acctPwd="xxx";
String contents="Message from Miss U:( \n Please be reminded that your friend:"+nickName+" is OUT of your setting area: "+setAname+". The current area is "+currAname+".";

String smsURL="http://api.accessyou.com/sms/sendsms-utf8.php?msg="+contents+"&phone="+toPhone+"&pwd="+acctPwd+"&accountno="+acctInfo;
response.sendRedirect(smsURL);
}
%>
```

Comment: What should `response` be referring to and why do you think so?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it will refer to a url. But, may I get your questions again?..

Comment: Wrong Approach! why are you expecting java to execute your code in between `<%! %>` .

Comment: Where does the `response` variable come from?

Comment: @A5l-lE5, it is a method I defined in the jsp file, the main body is in the later part which I omit it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, it seems no need to declare the response variable right?

Comment: Obviously it seems there is a need, otherwise you wouldn't get an exception.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bnaij/index.html

Comment: @Deepak2221 The article you linked refers to EL, not Java within scriptlets.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Btw you are correct. Here response should be pass as argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call your helper function you have to pass in the `response` object. Reason being that JSPs gets translated to Java Code, which is then compiled so it can run on JVM. Things between `<%!...%>` will get translated into helper methods that has different context than the code in `<%...%>`.

Your jsp will get translated into something like this:

```
public class MyJsp {

    public void doPost(HttpServletRrequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
      /* tons of code compiled off JSP */
      sendSMS(...)
    }

    private void sendSMS(String nickName, String setAnmae...) {

        String acctInfo="xxx";

        response.sendRedirect(...); // error, there is no response object in the local context
    }

}
```

Something like this would work

```
%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" 
                         pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.activation.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*,java.io.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>   

<%
 sendSMS(arg1, arg2, arg3, ar4, response)
%>

<%!
public void sendSMS(String nickName, 
                    String setAname, 
                    String currAname,                                                         
                    String toPhone,
                    ServletResponse response){
    String acctInfo="xxx";
    String acctPwd="xxx";
    String contents="Message from Miss U:( \n Please be reminded that your friend:"+nickName+" is OUT of your setting area: "+setAname+". The current area is "+currAname+".";

    String smsURL="http://api.accessyou.com/sms/sendsms-utf8.php?msg="+contents+"&phone="+toPhone+"&pwd="+acctPwd+"&accountno="+acctInfo;
    response.sendRedirect(smsURL);
}
%>
```

Notice how in `sendSMS` you don't have direct access to the `request` and `response` object.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work:(, should add the response in the function declare? ->public void sendSMS(String nickName, String setAname, String currAname,String toPhone)?

Comment: :P yes.. copy and paste error. Refresh and you will see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can Do it as below

```
 <%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>Page Redirection</title>
     </head>
    <body>
     <center>
      <h1>Page Redirection</h1>
     </center>
    <%
     // New location to be redirected
     String site = new String("http://www.xyz.com");
     response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
     response.setHeader("Location", site); 
    %>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: I can do it, but what I want now is to do it whthin a function.

Comment: @Shy Leng : Then you might have to use HttpServletResponse response as a param and then response.sendRedirect(smsURL);

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code:

```
<%! public void sendSMS(HttpServletResponse response){
try{
response.sendRedirect("th.jsp");}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
} %>
<%sendSMS(response); %>
```